undefined reference to `__res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE' got while installing krb5
During installing krb5 via brew install krb5, got this error:
gcc-14 -L../../lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath -Wl,~/opt/brew/Cellar/krb5/1.21.3/lib -g -O2   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../../include -I../../include  -DKRB5_DEPRECATED=1 -DKRB5_PRIVATE  -g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-format-zero-length -Woverflow -Wstrict-overflow
-Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wunknown-pragmas -Wsign-compare -Werror=uninitialized -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=int-conversion -Werror=incompatible-poin
ter-types -Werror=discarded-qualifiers -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pthread  -o test_getpw test_getpw.o -lkrb5support
~/opt/brew/opt/binutils/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE'


when I check the /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2, there is indeed such a symbol __res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE:
nm -D --with-symbol-versions /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 | grep __res_maybe_init
                 U __res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE

Further more, I tried to list shared library dependencies of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
$ ldd --verbose libresolv.so.2
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc5f106000)
        libc.so.6 (0x00007f03328cc000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0332e82000)

        Version information:
        ./libresolv.so.2:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => libc.so.6
        libc.so.6:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2


$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/opt/brew/opt/binutils/lib:~/opt/brew/lib:~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib:

$ find ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib -name "*libc.so*"
~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib/libc.so
~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib/libc.so.6


I think libresolv.so is supposed to depend on my own glibc under ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib/libc.so.6, but I don't know how to fix it
Any ideas else i can try?
